# select multiple files in upload dialog and save it to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash

Hi I'm implementing an image app with django. My question is not inherently connected with django. I want to add multiple upload forms, based on a number of files selected by a user in a dialog box, to the dom. I also want to save the selected files to a javascript array and populate the created forms with that values.
I'm not looking fo a fileuploader like swf upload. I just want to populate multiple forms by one selection.
Does somebody know a good plugin or libary to achieve that. Should I creata a flashmovie using FileReferenceList.browse() and pass it as json to the javascript?